# Error "NameError: name 'UsersAdmin' is not defined" when moved all classes to another file

Tags: python, class, flask-admin

Short story. I took this example:https://github.com/MrJoes/Flask-Admin/tree/master/examples/sqla i played with it and everything was fine until i decided what i want to split app.py(main file) to two parts. In main file app.py i will keep views and in another models.py i will keep all classes. Both files are in same folder.

Issue. I get error Error when running my app.py file:

> "NameError: name 'UserAdmin' is not defined"

This is part from app.py file where i try to call Class UserAdmin from models.py file:

```
import os
import os.path as op
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for, abort, session, flash
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy, Model
from flask_login import UserMixin, session, LoginManager, login_user, login_required, logout_user
from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt,check_password_hash,generate_password_hash
from models import *
from flask_admin import Admin, BaseView, expose
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = '123456790'
app.config['DATABASE_FILE'] = 'db.sqlite'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///' + app.config['DATABASE_FILE']
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_ECHO'] = True
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
bcrypt = Bcrypt(app)
admin = Admin(app, name='Admin Site', template_mode='bootstrap3')
# Add views. This is where it fails
admin.add_view(UserAdmin(User, db.session))
```

models.py file where is described UserAdmin part:

```
from wtforms import validators
from app import db, app, url_for, admin
from flask_admin.contrib import sqla
from flask_admin.contrib.sqla import filters, ModelView
from flask_login import UserMixin
...
# Create models
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(100))
    last_name = db.Column(db.String(100))
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True)

    # Required for administrative interface. For python 3 please use __str__ instead.
    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
class UserInfo(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    key = db.Column(db.String(64), nullable=False)
    value = db.Column(db.String(64))
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey(User.id))
    user = db.relationship(User, backref='info')
    def __str__(self):
        return '%s - %s' % (self.key, self.value)
class UserAdmin(sqla.ModelView):
    inline_models = (UserInfo,)
...
```

If someone could point me what i am doing wrong there it would be very nice.
Thanks

Comment: You should be importing `Models` not `models` if `Models.py` is the name of the file.

Comment: @zondo, sorry, it was a typo mistake when i was submitting this ticket. I will rename Models.py to models.py so it will not confuse anyone else. Thanks.

Comment: You give two arguments to UserAdmin. But i can't see the part of the class (__init__) taking the arguments, though name error points to a wrong import...

Comment: @AndreasMüller, i have added User class to my question. I would post a link to these two files, but i don't want to get negative votes. Full code is in GitHub repo, app.py file. Thanks.